# How to read a $_POST field sent from remote server in json format?

Tags: php, json

This is the code for the notification that I receive from the server that my work is complete. It returns a `$_POST` field, say `xyx`, in JSON format. I tried various combinations, even wrapping in `json_decode`, yet it returns `NULL`.

I also want to access a few values from the POST for further processing into database.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
echo "notification is arriving ...";
sleep(2);

//echo $_POST['message'];
//print_r($_POST,true);

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);  //CHECKING
?>
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

> notification is arriving ...NULL

EDIT :
AFter var_dump($_POST);

> array(2) { ["xyw"]=> string(2262) "{"ok":"ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED","message":"The assembly was successfully completed.","....and the rest of json output .

After var_dump("php://input")

> string(11) "php://input" .. If I remove quotes..nothing. Blank page .

Comment: Can you give an example var_dump of $_POST and php://input?

Comment: Why don't you turn errors back on then `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure there is actually data.  Also, `json_decode` will return `null` if the json string is invalid.

Comment: Why not just send it via parameter instead of raw post?

Comment: @Maerlyn I just did the var_dump and have edited with outputs .

Comment: @ArseniuszŁozicki but..my service provider is sending me notifications..

Comment: If you want your code to return a JSON object, you should replace json_decode for json_encode and then echo it. See my answer, it explains why your json_decode is returning NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Will return an ARRAY, not a json object. Thus, the following line:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

is trying to decode an array, and it will fail (because the type of $json is Array and not an json object.

Hope this answers your question.

## EDIT

If you want your script to return a json object, you should use json_encode instead and then echo it.

## EDIT2

To read, just do as follows:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myVar1 = $json['xyw'];
echo $myVar1;
```

## EDIT3

I've seen the output you have pasted and I see that it is a json string, you could encode it as follows:

```
$post= file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_encode($post['xyw']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did var_dump($json) then and it returned a blank page .Does it mean it`s not reading anything becuase I`m getting the json properly otherwise ..

Comment: What do you want your script to return? do you want it to return a json object?

Comment: I just want it to read the POST field sent me as json and then access it like an array or something to use futher.

Comment: if you want to read it like a json, use json_encode, but anyhow, you can just access it by doing as follows: See my EDIT2 in my answer.

Comment: See my EDIT3 also. Might help.